# Asp Hyperlink control in datagrid call javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript to open the page as pop-up. Now I need to call it on the datagrid, so I added the asp hyperlink control. I searched the web and found the example, but I got the "The server tag is not well formed." I spent a lot of time and cannot figure out how to correct my code. Would someone point it to me. Thanks in advance.

My code on aspx page

```
<asp:TemplateColumn headertext="Date Received" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" Itemstyle-wrap="False" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyTranscript" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="javascript:openWin('~/popAddEditReasons.aspx?page=Edit&ID=" & Eval("ID") &"','EditTransfer','width=650,height=325'); return false;")>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Received_Date", "{0:d MMM yyyy}").ToUpper%>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just go head and use an anchor tag.  The server control is not what you're looking for.  You're trying to set the onclick server-side event to a client-side function.  Which is wrong.  Unless you're looking to access this control server-side, just stick with the anchor tag.

That being said, the onclick event is way to complicated to be included in the markup.  You should have a protected function that kicks back the text you're looking for.  Like such.

```
protected string GetLink(string id)
{
    return "javascript:openWin('~/popAddEditReasons.aspx?page=Edit&ID=" + id + "','EditTransfer','width=650,height=325'); return false;";
}
```

Then update the markup to the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick='<% GetLink(Eval("ID")); %>'>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Received_Date", "{0:d MMM yyyy}").ToUpper() %>
        </a>
```

This hasn't been tested, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need server side events, the easiest way is to use the html a tag instead of ASP.Net HyperLink.

The following code basically calls an external javascript funciton to open a windows. It is much more cleaner than creating a link inside the onclick.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyTranscript" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" 
   onclick='<%# string.Format("openWindow(\"{0}\");", Eval("ID")) %>'>
    <%# Eval("Received_Date", "{0:d MMM yyyy}").ToUpper() %>
</asp:HyperLink>

<!-- I prefer this a tag -->
<a onclick='openWindow("<%# Eval("ID") %>")' href="#">
   <%# Eval("Received_Date", "{0:d MMM yyyy}").ToUpper() %>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(id) {
        // Note: you cannot use ~/ at client side.
        var url = "/popAddEditReasons.aspx?page=Edit&ID=" + id;
        window.open(url, "EditTransfer", "width=650,height=325");
    }
</script>
```